# Cannot pass guid as uniqueidentifier to storedprocedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I have a stored procedure that takes a uniqueidentifier as parameter.

It is supposed to work like this (I didn't write this):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[CheckActivation]", Conn)
{
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
};
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

where *key* is a string, but it does not. I alway get an 'Specified cast is not valid' exception.

So I rewrote it to:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(key);
using (var command = Conn.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "[CheckActivation]";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@key", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    command.Parameters["@key"].Value = guid;

    return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

guid is a Guid object with the correnct value, but I still get the same exception.

What is going wrong here?

Solution: The problem was the cast in the return statement. The sp returns an int value that cannot be casted to a bool:

return ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 1);

Comment: why do you have @key and @activationkey in your code? and can you show the sp?

Comment: Have you checked if the guid is correctly instantiated from your key string? Is key not empty?

Comment: instead of taking SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier take it as string and check, i think it should work

Comment: Please add your stored procedure code, it will provide more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Specified cast is not valid' means, that you are casting wrong and this is the only place you're doing this:

```
return (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Check this value. Either it is DBNull or another data type. Try debugging it, to find out the data type.

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)() doesn't return type bool:

> Type: System.Object
>
> The first column of the first row in
>   the result set, or a null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the
>   result set is empty. Returns a maximum
>   of 2033 characters.

Also, you create the parameter with the name "@key" and then use a different name in this line:

```
 command.Parameters["@activationkey"].Value = guid;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `@key` instead of `@activationkey`. Then you can add a parameter like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter 
  {
     ParameterName = "@key",
     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
     Value = new Guid(key)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify a parameter `"@key"`, as unique identifier type,

then you are setting the `guid` to parameter `"@activationkey"`, that has not been declared.

I think that you should instead of setting value to `"@activationkey"` it shluld be `key`

`command.Parameters["@key"].Value = guid;`